# How to use methods from a different project in an uitest project?

Tags: android, ant, android-uiautomator

I'm making some uitests with uiautomator for an android application in one project and I would need to use some methods in a different project. When I build the tests with ant I get the package `<X>` does not exist error.

Is there a way to use methods from a different project than the uitest project so that ant can recognize them?

I don't know how to add a whole project to the classpath of ant when I only have the source and it would be to tedious to always make a .jar out of the needed project. (As I understand it's only possible to add jars to the classpath)